# Struts2 + Spring : "No unique bean" error

Tags: spring, struts2

I start working on an old project which needed a struts upgrade (from 2.2.3.1 to 2.5.10.1)

But when I try to deploy I got those errors :

> ERROR SpringObjectFactory Error building bean 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.apache.struts2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through bean property 'localeProvider': : No
>   unique bean of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.LocaleProvider] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 32: [... List of
>   actions]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1167)
>     ... Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.LocaleProvider] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 32: [... same list of
>   actions]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:800)
>     ...

Every ActionSupport is a bean so I followed this example : 
https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/spring.html
Basically all that I've changed is declaring beans with 'id="blahblah"' instead of 'name="blahblah"'

For instance :

```
<bean scope="prototype" id="candidateAction" parent="goalAction"
        class="fr.hec.goal.back.actions.CandidateAction">
        <property name="pageId" value="CreateCandidate" />
        <property name="programService" ref="programService" />
        <property name="sessionService" ref="admissionSessionService" />
        <property name="candidateService" ref="candidateService" />
    </bean>
```

And all the injected beans are also with "id" instead of "name" now.

But I still got the error.

Any idea?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the setting in the struts.xml for the auto wire strategy:

http://struts.apache.org/plugins/spring/

```
<constant name="struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire" value="name" />
```

[image: Struts2 Spring Auto Wire Options]

Based on your stack trace, I would say this is probably configured for "type" at the moment and you have multiple beans with the same type.  Try to change this to "name" to get your desired result